# Connecting to Database inside Class and method nothing happens?

Tags: php, database, class, methods, connection

I am trying to add my code I use to connect to my database to a class and method. When not inside class it echo connection successful.  But with new code I don't get anything. No error or success? Should I even be putting this inside a class and using a method?

```
<?php

class DBconfig
{

    private $servername = "localhost";
    private $username = "*********";
    private $password = "***************";


    // public function __construct($servername,$username,$password)
    // {

    //     $this -> servername = $servername;
    //     $this -> username = $username;
    //     $this -> password = $password;
    // }


    public function dbConnect($servername,$username,$password)
    {

            // $servername = $this -> servername;
            // $username = $this -> username;
            // $password = $this -> password;

        try 
        {

            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername; dbname = training", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "Connected successfully";
        } 

            catch(PDOException $e) 
        {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

        }
        
    }
}


    
?>
```

AS you can see I have tried a couple of things that are commented out. These did not help.

Comment: Where are you instantiating the class and calling the function? You haven't shown us that part

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some changes added to the code below. it works fine

```
   class DBconfig
{

private $servername = "localhost";
private $db = "**************";
private $username = "**************";
private $password = "**************";

private $conn;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->dbConnect();
}

public function dbConnect()
{
    try 
    {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servername; dbname = $this->db", $this->username, $this->password);
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully";
    } 

    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function getConnection(){
    return $this->conn;
}
}

$db = new DBconfig();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
```

Comment: You should point out the changes and why you did them, exactly, then people can understand, rather than just copying and hoping

Comment: no problem. You can [edit] your answer when you're ready.

Comment: Thank you Ali Usama I see all the places I messed up. I appreciated the help time to go over classes and methods again to try to get better understanding.